# Gravar Datagrid (C# + Firebird)

Tags: c#, firebird, datagrid

Já tentei vários foruns sobre mas to tendo problema para gravar os dados da datagrid no firebird
Segue o codigo

```
private void toolStripButton_salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FbConnection con = new FbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=meubanco.fbd;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;\r\nServerType=0;";
        string _sql = "insert into TB_FORMAPGTO (TIPO, @ARCELAS, DIAS 1, DIAS 2, DIAS 3, DIAS 4, DIAS 5) values (@TIPO, @PARCELAS, @DIAS 1, @DIAS 2, @DIAS 3, @DIAS 4, @DIAS 5)";
      
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(_sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TIPO", comboBox_tipopgto.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARCELAS", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["parcelas"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS 1", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia1"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS 2", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia2"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS 3", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia3"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS 4", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia4"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS 5", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["Dia5"].Value);

            cmd.CommandText = _sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Forma de Pagamento salvo", "Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro!" + ex, "Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Porem retona os erros do print. Alguem pode me ajudar ?
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psfiq.jpg)

Eu não fiz um For pois é somente 1 linha de inserção do `datagrid`, logo o "0" se repete informando que é dessa linha `dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se não me engano creio que os parametros no componente Command tem que ser sem espaço, e como está a query na variavel **_sql**?

Creio que o código deveria estar mais ou menos assim

```
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(_sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TIPO", comboBox_tipopgto.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARCELAS", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["parcelas"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS_1", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia1"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS_2", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia2"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS_3", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia3"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS_4", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["dia4"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIAS_5", dataGridView_tipopgto.Rows[0].Cells["Dia5"].Value);

            cmd.CommandText = _sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Forma de Pagamento salvo", "Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro!" + ex, "Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

E o conteúdo da variavel _sql desta forma

```
string _sql = "insert into TB_FORMAPGTO (TIPO, PARCELAS, DIAS1, DIAS2, DIAS3, DIAS4, DIAS5) values (@TIPO, @PARCELAS, @DIAS_1, @DIAS_2, @DIAS_3, @DIAS_4, @DIAS_5)";
```

Espero ter ajudado meu amigo.

Comment: Vdd !!! Ajustei e deu certo ! Obrigado mesmo! 
Erro da query com espaço